# What is the most efficient way to populate a listview?

Tags: android, listview, view, android-listview, populate

I have an app which mains view is a listview. Each item consist of multiple textviews and imageviews. Now, what is the most efficient way to populate these items? String arrays? External text file? Online text files?

for example this is an item in the listview:
[image]

The listview will contain over 50 items and these items will increase every week. So it should be as easy as possible to add new items!

Comment: Depends on what is your data for listview? Is it dynamic (or) static?

Comment: Where is the ListView **data** coming from?

Comment: It should be static, but whenever I update the app with new items, it should be as easy as possible to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you pick an efficient way that works for YOUR project.
I would recommend just using an SQLite database for such. 
You could use Text files, but you have a database availible for such, so i would recommend using it.

Here is more info on SQLite and how to get started using it.

EDIT:

Also you could possibly use online text files. And just read the information from them. This may take some time when populating the list, so i would recommend doing this in he background, and trying to write the information to a abase.

[Using SQLite and getting started](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: Ahhh, this might work. I'll try if it does the job for me. Thanks!